# Ubuntu 12.04 - Installing nvidia-current driver fails

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

**EDIT**

After trying a lot of things I gave up and I installed Ubuntu 14.04. Now I can simply install the proprietary drivers selecting them in the *Additional drivers* settings.

---

I'm trying to install the nvidia drivers for my notebook but I'm having a lot of troubles...

First some info on my system. I have `Ubuntu 12.04` 64 bit, `lspci` gives:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

the kernel is `3.5.0-54-generic`.

I have installed the `nvidia-current` package but then I ended with a screen resolution of 640x480. So I purged `nvidia` stuff, I removed the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and I got back my system using the `nouveau` driver.

How can I install the nvidia drivers?

In my repos there are other packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-

nvidia-173                        nvidia-331-updates-uvm            nvidia-current-updates-dev
nvidia-173-dev                    nvidia-331-uvm                    nvidia-experimental-304
nvidia-173-updates                nvidia-96                         nvidia-experimental-304-dev
nvidia-173-updates-dev            nvidia-96-dev                     nvidia-experimental-310
nvidia-304                        nvidia-96-updates                 nvidia-experimental-310-dev
nvidia-304-dev                    nvidia-96-updates-dev             nvidia-opencl-dev
nvidia-304-updates                nvidia-cg-toolkit                 nvidia-prime
nvidia-304-updates-dev            nvidia-common                     nvidia-screenlet
nvidia-319                        nvidia-compute-profiler           nvidia-settings
nvidia-319-dev                    nvidia-cuda-dev                   nvidia-settings-304
nvidia-319-updates                nvidia-cuda-doc                   nvidia-settings-304-updates
nvidia-319-updates-dev            nvidia-cuda-gdb                   nvidia-settings-319
nvidia-331                        nvidia-cuda-toolkit               nvidia-settings-319-updates
nvidia-331-dev                    nvidia-current                    nvidia-settings-experimental-304
nvidia-331-updates                nvidia-current-dev                nvidia-settings-experimental-310
nvidia-331-updates-dev            nvidia-current-updates            nvidia-settings-updates
```

but I don't know which else I can try...

If I understood correctly my pc has the optimus technology that is it has two graphics cards, one Intel and the other is the Nvidia one. Some comments on forums seem to suggest that this technology is supported in Ubuntu less than 13 only installing [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/), is that correct?

If I upgrade my system to Ubuntu 14.04 the problem remains the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing the driver `nvidia-common`:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
```

then reboot.

Comment: Installing `nvidia-current` also install `nvidia-common`

Answer (score 0):

Go into your system bios and disable the Intel graphics core.  Nvidia drivers work like a charm on 12.04 after that.